# Access Denied 403 forbidden

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'am trying to encrypt password in sign up and its work, when i post sign up it saved in db and the password encrypted. 
But the other api becomes access denied, for example when i try to login or get all user it give me forbidden 403 "access denied" what the wrong in my code?

this is my security class

```
package com.user.user.config.security;

import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
{
private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

public static final String SIGN_UP_URL = "/registration";
public WebSecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, 
BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers 
(HttpMethod.POST, 
SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
}
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws 
Exception {

auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService) 
.passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
 }
}
```

and this is method in class services

```
public List<Users> getAllUsers() {
    List<Users> users = new ArrayList<>();
    userRepository.findAll()
            .forEach(users::add);
    return users;
}

 public void registration(Users users) {
    //   
 users.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder  
.encode(users.getPassword()));
 users.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder 
.encode(users.getPassword()));
 userRepository.save(users);
 }
```

and i added this method in main class

```
 @Bean
  public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
     return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }
```

what i should to do to fix my problem ??

Comment: Did you add access token on each request?

Comment: no i did't, but the intillij give me security password and i tried to put in post me with username: user and its not work.

Answer (score 0):

Its work when i Edit this function

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers( "/registration","/users","/login")
            .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

but swagger not work what i should add to make it work?

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing 
this as a fallback.

Wed Dec 26 18:31:49 EET 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Access Denied
```

Comment: access denied @JonathanJohx

Comment: Did you add your password and username or access token to swagger?

Comment: No, he did't ask me for username and password, what should i do ?

Comment: You can see this example of swagger that has authorize button https://petstore.swagger.io where you need to put username and password

Comment: And review this link to implement it https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/basic-authentication/

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? I am having the same issue. I have two clients one for react-web and one for node-js API. I got successfully log in from the browser but when access the API it gives me an access denied error??